# Кракозябры в JavaScript файле. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Как решить проблему кракозябристого текста в placeholder русских символов которые передаются в HTML через JavaScript, innerHTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Не помогает

Comment: Какая кодировка файлов, заголовки сервера, что говорит декодер лебедева при попытке преобразования?

Comment: я не знаю. Я только meta charset UTF8 сделал в HTML файле. Про остальное Вами сказанное я не знаю как проверить.

Да и только в placeholder так

Comment: Заголовки можно посмотреть в консоли хрома/лисы. Но у вас в целом вопрос не конкретизирован и ошибка может быть в чем угодно. В utf-8 дефис не забыли?

Comment: @navi1893 "Зачитайте, пжалста, весь список". Приведите минимальный неработающий пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Если указываете для html документа кодировку utf-8, то и сам файл yourfile.htm должен быть сохранен в этой кодировке. Откройте его например в Notepad ++ и воспользуйтесь меню "Кодировки"

Comment: Encoding = UTF8